# Maven Coding Styles

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

i have included the maven check style reporting plugin in my pom.xml file as following

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

I am using eclipse for my  development, and got the maven java coding conventions from [here](http://maven.apache.org/developers/conventions/code.html). Now if i format all of my code, and run the mvn site tool it still reports check style errors. Is there any way i can format my code to pass all the check style errors in my code ?

**EDIT**
I have placed a check style suppressions.xml file in the root of my project. This contains the following

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
     "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="JavadocStyleCheck"
             files=*.java"
             lines="0-99999999"/>
  
</suppressions>
```

I then configure this in my pom.xml file as

```
<reporting>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.10</version>
                <configuration>
                    <suppressionsLocation>
                        checkstyle-suppressions.xml
                    </suppressionsLocation>
                    <suppressionsFileExpression>
                        checkstyle.suppressions.file
                    </suppressionsFileExpression>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </reporting>
```

I want the java doc checkstyle error skipped during the mvn site generation. But i still am recieving this ? What am i doing wrong ?

Kind Regards

Comment: Yes. _(Show us the error message and the code if you want more details)_

Answer (score 0):

The [Using a Suppressions Filter](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/suppressions-filter.html) told us as

> Checkstyle allows the definition of a list of files and their line ranges that should be suppressed from reporting any violations (known as a [suppressions filter](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config.html#Filters) ).

#### Example: checkstyle-suppressions.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<!DOCTYPE suppressions PUBLIC
     "-//Puppy Crawl//DTD Suppressions 1.0//EN"
     "http://www.puppycrawl.com/dtds/suppressions_1_0.dtd">

<suppressions>
  <suppress checks="JavadocStyleCheck"
             files="GeneratedObject.java"
             lines="50-9999"/>
  <suppress checks="MagicNumberCheck"
             files="LegacyDatasetConvertor.java"
             lines="221,250-295"/>
</suppressions>
```

#### Example: pom.xml - Specifies the suppressions filter that Checkstyle should use.

```
<project>
  ...
  <reporting>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <configuration>
          <configLocation>checkstyle.xml</configLocation>
          <suppressionsLocation>
            checkstyle-suppressions.xml
          </suppressionsLocation>
          <suppressionsFileExpression>
            checkstyle.suppressions.file
          </suppressionsFileExpression>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </reporting>
  ...
</project>
```

**EDITED**

The [Using a Custom Checkstyle Checker Configuration](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-checkstyle-plugin/examples/custom-checker-config.html)

> can be defined and then referenced via a URL, File, or build classpath resource reference.
>   To reference a custom Checkstyle Checker configuration, use the configLocation parameter.

There are 4 predefined Checkstyle configuration definitions that ship with the Checkstyle Plugin, the Sun Microsystems Definition is selected by default.

1. config/sun_checks.xml - Sun Microsystems Definition (default).
2. config/maven_checks.xml - Maven Development Definitions.
3. config/turbine_checks.xml - Turbine Development Definitions.
4. config/avalon_checks.xml - Avalon Development Definitions.

I hope this may help.

Comment: The maven formatter, places the { on a new line where as the check style expects the { on the same line ? These two seem to be out of sync ?

Comment: I have edited my answer by adding the Using a Custom Checkstyle Checker Configuration.

Comment: so how can i use the Sun checkstyle in Eclipse as well ? If there any xml file i can download to place in eclipse, so that when i format my code in eclipse, the check style checks passes

Comment: Please go to `windows --> preferences ---> Java ---> Formatter`. There is a pre-define `Java Conventions` at the ``Active Profile` drop-down list.